# Checking if inputted strings are equal to strings in list?

Tags: python, string, list, function, input

I'm working on a project that involves building a simplified version of a calendar agent that asks the user for when they want to schedule an appointment and does it for them (if that slot is free). This is the code I have so far:

```
def find_index(val, seq):
for index in range(len(seq)):
    place = seq[index]
    if place == val:
        return index
    else:
        return int("-1")

def find_val(val, seq):
    for ele in seq:
        if val == ele:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def init_nested_list(size_outer, size_inner):
    cal = []
    for outer_index in range(size_outer):
        nested_list = []
        for inner_index in range(size_inner):
            nested_list.append("-")
        cal.append(nested_list)
    return cal

def get_input(possible_vals, day_or_time_string):
    count = 0
    if day_or_time_string == "day":
        answer = input("What day would you like your appointment? ")
    else:
        answer = input("What time would you like your appointment? ")
    answer = answer.strip()
    nested_list = find_val(answer, possible_vals)
    while answer in possible_vals:
        break
    else:
        count = count + 1
        answer = input("Invalid entry. Please enter a valid day: ")
        if count == 3:
            print("This is getting silly - still not a valid entry")
            answer = input("Please do try to enter a valid day: ")
            count = 0
    return answer

def book_slot(cal,days_labels, times_labels, day, time): **ignore this function, haven't finished it yet**
    find_index(day, days_labels)

def start_scheduler(cal, days_labels, times_labels):
    while True:
        day = get_input(days_labels, "day")
        time = get_input(times_labels, "time")
        book_slot( cal, days_labels, times_labels, day, time)
        print("--------------------------------- ")
        res = input("Did you want to book more appointments (type n for no, any other key for yes)? ")
        if res == "n":
            break

days_labels= ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday"]
times_labels = ["9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5"]
calendar = init_nested_list(len(days_labels), len(times_labels))

print("Welcome to the acupuncture booking system. ")
start_scheduler(calendar, days_labels, times_labels)
```

This is what the complete output should look like so far:

```
 Welcome to the acupuncture booking system. 
 What day would you like your appointment? saturday
 Invalid entry. Please enter a valid day: Monday
 What time would you like your appointment? 24
 Invalid entry. Please enter a valid time: 9
 --------------------------------- 
 Did you want to book more appointments (type n for no, any other key for yes)?
```

However, it seems that no matter what I input when the function asks me for the date/time of the appointment, it doesn't check to see if the inputted strings are equivalent to any of the acceptable ones (in the lists days_labels and times labels). Instead it just accepts any second random input to be correct as shown:

```
Welcome to the acupuncture booking system. 
What day would you like your appointment? s
Invalid entry. Please enter a valid day: z
What time would you like your appointment? d
Invalid entry. Please enter a valid day: f
--------------------------------- 
Did you want to book more appointments (type n for no, any other key for yes)?
```

What needs to be done in order to have the function check to see if the inputted strings correspond with any of the strings in the days_labels and times_labels lists in order for the user to "book" an appointment?

Answer (score 0):

So you wont to create a function to check if any inputted string have been already used.
There reason your code isnt working correctly is because you tried to check wherethere your counter is up to 3, while it isnt any loop, and thus it only ascends to 1.
To re-arrange that to a correct way for example, you would do this:

```
while answer not in possible_values:
<your code here>
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't test this at all but it should be enough to guide you to fix your incrementing error.

```
def isValidDayInput(input):
    accept = false
    # your code here
    return accept


def dayInput(count, maxAttempts):
    waiting = true
    while (waiting && count <= maxAttempts):
           answer = promptForInput()
           if (isValidDayInput(answer)): # accept returned true during validation
               waiting = false # answer is valid so jump out loop
           else(): # accept returned false during validation
               count += 1
   if (!waiting && count == maxAttempts):
          print("Too many incorrect attempts. Exit")
   else:
          print("thank you")
```